# Condição If/Else em uma coluna (python)

Tags: python

Necessito construir um if/else em uma coluna na tabela [6]. Segue o print do resultado (sem o if/else aplicado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_dados=
```

'http://sistemasinter.cetesb.sp.gov.br/Ar/php/ar_dados_horarios_resultado.php'

```
r = requests.get(url_dados)


payload =  {'texData':'27/02/2018',
            'selEst':'5/Ibirapuera'}

response = requests.post(url_dados, data=payload)


with open('dados_ibira.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.text.encode("utf8"))


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[6]
NO2_Ibirapuera = pd.read_html(str(table).replace(",", "."))


print(NO2_Ibirapuera)
```

Com isso o if/else é para ser aplicado nessa coluna com as seguintes condições:

```
0 - 40 = Boa  
41 - 80 = Moderada  
81 - 120 = Ruim  
121 - 200 = Muito Ruim 
> 200 = Péssima
```

Estou confuso em relação a separação da coluna e a aplicação do if/else.

Answer (score 2):

Ola,já peço desculpa por qualquer erro antecipadamente.

Por utilizar o pandas, a fileira que está abaixo do [, foi posta pelo Pandas, é o índice da tabela, logo não conta, dá para retirar.

Agora, o seu objeto NO2_Ibirapuera está na seguite organização,

NO2_Ibirapuera = Objeto direto, não tem o acesso direto a tabela.
NO2_Ibirapuera[0] = E a sua tabela.
NO2_Ibirapuera[0][0] = sua primeira coluna.
NO2_Ibirapuera[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gd4x.png) = sua Segunda coluna.

Agora só utilizar NO2_Ibirapuera[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gd4x.png)[x], para definir o argumento x, com o valor que deseja.

vamos criar uma função com as condições:

```
def condition(var):

if var == "--":
    return "--"

if 0 <= var <= 40:
    return "Boa"

if 41 <= var <= 80:
    return "Moderada"

if 81 <= var <= 120:
    return "Ruim"

if 121 <= var <= 200:
    return "Muito Ruim"

return "Péssima"
```

Agora passar os dados pela função:

```
for x in range(len(NO2_Ibirapuera[0][0])):
try:
    NO2_Ibirapuera[0][1][x] = condition(int(NO2_Ibirapuera[0][0][x]))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Por que o try e o except ? Pois como tenho que transformar o dado da tabela em inteiro(int), se for uma letra irá aparecer um erro, assim com o except esse item será ignorado, indo para o proximo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo final :

```html
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_dados='http://sistemasinter.cetesb.sp.gov.br/Ar/php/ar_dados_horarios_resultado.php'

r = requests.get(url_dados)


payload =  {'texData':'27/02/2018',
            'selEst':'5/Ibirapuera'}

response = requests.post(url_dados, data=payload)


with open('dados_ibira.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.text.encode("utf8"))


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[6]
NO2_Ibirapuera = pd.read_html(str(table).replace(",", "."))


def condition(var):

    if var == "--":
        return "--"
    
    if 0 <= var <= 40:
        return "Boa"
    
    if 41 <= var <= 80:
        return "Moderada"
    
    if 81 <= var <= 120:
        return "Ruim"
    
    if 121 <= var <= 200:
        return "Muito Ruim"
    
    return "Péssima"


for x in range(len(NO2_Ibirapuera[0][0])):
    try:
        NO2_Ibirapuera[0][1][x] = condition(int(NO2_Ibirapuera[0][0][x]))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(NO2_Ibirapuera)

# Com isso o if/else é para ser aplicado nessa coluna com as seguintes condições:
#
# 0 - 40 = Boa
# 41 - 80 = Moderada
# 81 - 120 = Ruim
# 121 - 200 = Muito Ruim
# > 200 = Péssima
```

Vlw, abraços. Qualquer duvida, só perguntar.